# Parse xml using Java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help me to parse the following xml using Java

I need to get the "Total Contract Value (Gross NBA)" row values for 3 columns. I tried with Document Builder and SAXParser, as the format is confusing, please help me to get it fixed

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet'?>
<s:Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <s:Styles>
    <s:Style s:ID="REGULAR">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="BOLD">
      <s:Alignment s:Vertical="Bottom" s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:Bold="1" s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="REGULAR_NO_WRAP">
      <s:Alignment />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="DATE">
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:NumberFormat s:Format="Short Date" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="LINK">
      <s:Alignment />
      <s:Font s:Underline="Single" s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#0000FF" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="COLUMN_HEAD">
      <s:Alignment s:Horizontal="Center" s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:Bold="1" s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#FFFFFF" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#6CA76F" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="COLUMN_SUBHEAD">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#006600" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#B5D6B7" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#D2E3FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT_BOLD">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:Bold="1" s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#D2E3FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT_SUBTLE">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#E7F0FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT_LINK">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:Underline="Single" s:FontName="Arial" s:Size="14" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#D2E3FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="GRANDTOTAL">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:Bold="1" s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#F0F0F0" s:Pattern="Solid" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#D2E3FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
      <s:NumberFormat s:Format="_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* 0.00_);_(@_)" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="REGULAR_C">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:NumberFormat s:Format="_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* 0.00_);_(@_)" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="HIGHLIGHT_P">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:Interior s:Color="#D2E3FF" s:Pattern="Solid" />
      <s:NumberFormat s:Format="Percent" />
    </s:Style>
    <s:Style s:ID="REGULAR_P">
      <s:Alignment s:WrapText="1" />
      <s:Font s:FontName="Arial" s:Color="#000000" />
      <s:NumberFormat s:Format="Percent" />
    </s:Style>
  </s:Styles>
  <s:Worksheet s:Name="Service">
    <s:Table>
      <s:Column s:Width="170" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Column s:Width="80" />
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="BOLD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Project</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="REGULAR_NO_WRAP">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">VNNWASXX-VENWAS</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="BOLD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Forecast Period</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="REGULAR_NO_WRAP">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Oct 2015</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="BOLD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Page</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="REGULAR_NO_WRAP">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Revenue Details</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="BOLD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Currency</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="REGULAR_NO_WRAP">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">EUR</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String" />
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Usa / Canada</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Europe / Africa</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Asia / Pacific</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">EDS - EU Clinic</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="COLUMN_HEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Total</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:MergeAcross="5" s:StyleID="COLUMN_SUBHEAD">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Contract</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT">
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Total Contract Value (Gross NBA)</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
          <s:Data s:Type="Number">33181</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
          <s:Data s:Type="Number">75425.67</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
          <s:Data s:Type="Number">0</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
          <s:Data s:Type="Number">0</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell s:StyleID="HIGHLIGHT_C">
          <s:Data s:Type="Number">108606.67</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
```

I tried using the following code

```
public void readXMLFile(String fileName){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = builder.parse(fileName);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NodeList labTestList = doc.getElementsByTagName("s:Worksheet");
    for (int i = 0; i < labTestList.getLength(); ++i)
    {
        Element labTest = (Element) labTestList.item(i);
        String labTestType = labTest.getAttribute("s:Name");

        NodeList valueList = labTest.getElementsByTagName("s:Row");
        for (int j = 0; j < valueList.getLength(); ++j)
        {
            Element value = (Element) valueList.item(j);
            String valueType = value.getAttribute("s:Type");

            NodeList conditionList = value.getElementsByTagName("s:Cell");
            for (int k = 0; k < conditionList.getLength(); ++k)
            {
```

Comment: add what yiou tried and what errors or the confusing part is

Comment: As it stands, your question does not seem to be clear. Please include some error messages that you have receive and possibly some sample of your Java code you are using to parse the XML.

Comment: I couldnt add the whole code as it shows some error while clicks save edit button, how ever, i have updated with some part. please take a look

Comment: You seem to be conflating namespaces and tag names. Please read up on the XML format.

Comment: I didnt understand, Could you please ellaborate

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned what errors you've gotten, which would help a lot, but I would suggest using [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) to navigate your xml once it's in document form.  The methods `getAttribute()` and `getElementByTagName()` can be difficult to get reliable and helpful results from.

The xpath expression would be something like this:

```
String expression = "/s:Workbook/s:Styles/s:Worksheet";
```

This would give you the Node containing the Total Contract Value.  You could then take the `lastChildNode()` and navigate through the cells.

Comment: Please provide a method to read the attribute Total Contract Value (Gross NBA)"

Comment: Try section 1.4 at this link: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as easily as you suggest - the OP would certainly have to configure a namespace context in the XPath engine at the very least. Which leads us back to the OP having to understand what exactly a namespace is and what `s:Workbook` actually means.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the corresponding xsd, you can generate jaxb pojo classes or write pojo with jaxb annotations and namespaces, and use jaxb unmarshalling to map whole xml into a java object. HTH

Comment: This is for testing purpose, i need to read this xml file and compare it with the application